# Google Analytics - is there a way to setup cross-domain tracking for 50+ different domains?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

As per the title. 
Iimagine 50+ different domains - www.site1.com, www.site2.com... - with no direct link to each other. 
The need is to have all the websites tracked in the same GA property without duplicating users, there is no cross-domain funnel or conversion path to follow.

I'm used to cross-domain tracking between 2-3 different domains, via link decoration or GTM configuration, but now I have difficulty in understanding what should be the best way to link all the domains without having to resort to manually listing them in the tracking tag, which I expect to break anyways.

Anyone experienced similar issues?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Cross-domain tracking between 50 domains has the same approach as cross-domain tracking between 2 domains. You can't avoid listing them all.

Pay attention to the byte limits on the fields, which should be 500 characters long. The documentation says this but it cannot be excluded that it can contain more characters than the declared ones.